# Visual Studio CODE VSCODE dose not run in docker

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I installed VSCODE in docker but it dose not works. can anybody help me how to add VSCODE to an existing docker image. I tried to much but did not succeed by any way.

I have a docker image with vnc login into it. i want to install VSCODE into it. but whenever i install VSCODE dose not work. please help me

Comment: Information about the docker image is required. Different information about what the FROM image is, what the operating architecture is, or if there is a link to refer to. Also, there are many images with vscode installed in the docker hub. Refer to the Dockerfiles of the images

Comment: you can see below ref [sebmoule/docker-vscode/dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/sebmoule/docker-vscode/dockerfile) [exadra37/visual-studio-code/dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/exadra37/visual-studio-code/dockerfile)

Comment: Will try it and inform if it works for me or not